# href links goes wrong in dynamic web project

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, href

There are the follow jsp pages  -

`default.jsp` under `WebContent`

`EmployeeMenu.jsp` under `WebContent/MenuPages`

`selectAccountToRemoveOwner.jsp` under `WebContent/ActionsPages`

I have the follow running between servlets and jsp pages  -

firstly  - `default.jsp`  -

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Site.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Create new customer</title>
</head>
<body>
    </script>
    <form action="loginCheckServlet" method="POST">
        //form ... 
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Goes to  - `loginCheckServlet` to `doPost` -

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            // forward to employee page ..
            String addressMenuPage = "MenuPages/"
                    +"EmployeeMenu.jsp";
            RequestDispatcher dispather = 
                    request.getRequestDispatcher(addressMenuPage);
            // go to this page ...
            dispather.forward(request, response) ; 
    }
```

Goes to  - `EmployeeMenu.jsp` -

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
           <a href="ActionsPages/selectAccountToRemoveOwner.jsp">Remove owner from
                    account</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Goes to `selectAccountToRemoveOwner.jsp` -

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="../MenuPages/EmployeeMenu.jsp">Return to Employee menu</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Goes back to `EmployeeMenu.jsp` .

Until here all the links works fine . But now if I press again on the link in `EmployeeMenu.jsp` in order to get in `selectAccountToRemoveOwner.jsp` I get  -

```
HTTP Status 404 - /MyBankProject/MenuPages/ActionsPages/selectAccountToRemoveOwner.jsp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /MyBankProject/MenuPages/ActionsPages/selectAccountToRemoveOwner.jsp

description The requested resource (/MyBankProject/MenuPages/ActionsPages/selectAccountToRemoveOwner.jsp) is not available.
```

Note that the message refers to `/MenuPages/ActionsPages` location that indeed not exist  . It seems like the transition from `EmployeeMenu.jsp` to `selectAccountToRemoveOwner.jsp` had not change the current folder location .

Comment: EmployeeMenu.jsp  change href tag to <a href="/ActionsPages/selectAccountToRemoveOwner.jsp...>

Comment: instead of relative path can't you use real path? like this "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" with the help of JSTL core tags

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer seems to be modifying the href of the link in the file EmployeeMenu.jsp so that it appears like so:

`<a href="../ActionsPages/selectAccountToRemoveOwner.jsp">`

The relative link in EmployeeMenu.jsp gets appended to the current context path which I believe is "/MyBankProject/MenuPages/".